# Nlog output characters if exception not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

Is there a way in Nlog to output certain character only if Exception is not null.  For example my layout is:

```
layout="${longdate}|${callsite:skipFrames=1}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
```

If I call `NLog.Debug("Hello")` the output will be:

```
2015-12-07 11:50:00.5114|MyDll.MyClass.MyMethod|Hello|
```

That last character `|` is being printed out.  Is there a way to prevent this, and only print it out if there is an actual exception being printed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Also look at "When" Layout Renderer

```
${when:when=Condition:inner=Layout}
```

EDIT by OP to show working solution for future visitors:

```
layout="${longdate}|${callsite:skipFrames=1}|${message}${when:when=length('${exception}')>0:Inner=|}${exception:format=tostring}"
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `${onexception:INNER}` layout renderer for this.

```
${message}${onexception:|${exception:format=Type,Message,StackTrace,Data}}
```

If there is an exception, it will prepend a '|' followed by whatever you specifiy as your exception format. If no exception is present, only the ${message} will be rendered.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the `exceptionSeparator` parameter of `$(message)`, this is only output if there is an exception. Eg. to give a space between message an exception:

```
<variable name="StdLayout" 
value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message:exceptionSeparator= }${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

Comment: so instead of a space I can put `|` after the `=` in the message clause?  This will cause the `|` to be printed out only if there is an exception?

Comment: I tried that with `layout="${longdate}|${callsite:skipFrames=1}|${message:exceptionSeparator=|}${exception:format=tostring}"` and it didn't print it out.  I also tried it with a space and it still did not work.  When exception is there, it does not get printed out.

Comment: My first check would be on nLog versions... but I've currently only got limited access to the project containing the above configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I will Combine two above answers

- using `when` layout render like [@skalinkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34139199/1908296) answer But I think preferred use exception's message for detect exception if null or not,  Like this

```
layout="${longdate}|${message}${when:when=length('${exception:format=tostring}')>0:Inner=|}${exception:format=tostring}"
```

- using `onexception` layout render like [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47154976/1908296) answer

```
layout="${longdate}|${message}${onexception:inner=|Exception\: ${exception:format=tostring}}"
```

For More Details about suggested layouts Here Official Doc

- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer
- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/OnException-Layout-Renderer

**I Preferred to use the second Suggest**

Answer (score 1):

You can define a target which explicitly test if exception is not null :

```
<target name="fileAsException"
        xsi:type="FilteringWrapper"
        condition="length('${exception}')>0">
  <target xsi:type="File"
          fileName="c:\my path\exceptions.log"
          layout="${ExceptionVerboseLayout}" />
</target>
```

(See the "condition="length('${exception}')>0">" line)
You can bind it with a specific layout ("ExceptionVerboseLayout" in my example).

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding how this works, would you be able to give me an example based on my question above?  What is confusing me is that you are putting a target inside a target, how does it know which message to show?  I still need Regular message to be displayed.

Comment: I answer you even if you already found your solution :). The syntax is a little bit confusing. It's a single target, not one included in another. To display regular messages along with exceptions you can use skalinkin answer, it will be simpler.